# Honeycomb notifications - How to set largeIcon to the right size?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-notifications

I find myself curious why the setLargeIcon method on Notification.Builder only accepts a Bitmap, with no overload to provide a resource id. Perhaps it was done for performance reasons, but it seems odd as setSmallIcon does accept a res drawable id.

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(application);
// ....
builder.setLargeIcon(iconBitmap);  // Requires a Bitmap
builder.setSmallIcon(iconResId);   // Requires a drawable resource ID
Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
```

Sadly the bitmap provided is not scaled in the notification, so the Bitmap needs to be provided exactly the right size for the notification view.

Assuming I need to provide xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi versions of the largeIcon bitmap, what sizes do they need to be? I can see no mention in the docs, or after scouring the wider web.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Not had a chance to check it yet but API 11 introduced the following public dimens:

- [notification_large_icon_height](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.dimen.html#notification_large_icon_height)
- [notification_large_icon_width](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.dimen.html#notification_large_icon_width)

Should be able to use those to scale your image before setting it on the notification.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Do you know what units those values are in (17104902, 17104901)?

Comment: They are most likely dp's in the xml. When you use Resources. getDimensionPixelSize() you'll get them in px.

Comment: Thanks guys. This does the trick nicely. I figure the reason it requires a Bitmap not a resId is it's designed for social media use, and peoples' faces won't typically be distributed with the app.
width = res.getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width)

Comment: That's 64dp x 64dp https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml#L150

Comment: 64 dp x 64 dp is also supported by [this answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/15778/13327) on Graphic Design

Comment: So the best solution is: `int width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width);`
`int height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height);`

Answer (score 61):

I used the [dimensions of the notification's large icon](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.dimen.html#notification_large_icon_height) to create a scaled bitmap

```
BitmapDrawable contactPicDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) ContactsUtils.getContactPic(mContext, contactId);
Bitmap contactPic = contactPicDrawable.getBitmap();

Resources res = mContext.getResources();
int height = (int) res.getDimension(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height);
int width = (int) res.getDimension(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width);
contactPic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(contactPic, width, height, false);
```

And then I set the large icon with this scaled bitamp.

Comment: You might consider storing the result into a new variable Bitmap scaledContactPic and  adding if(!contactPic.equals(scaledContactPic)){ contactPic.recycle(); }