# Android system theme adding its own background to the icon of notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, notification-icons

I've created a simple notification using `NotificationCompat`.
Following is my code

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon)
        .setTicker(title)
        .setWhen(0)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle())
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
        .setContentText(message);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Here is the output on my device.

[image]

My icon does not have the blue gradient background. The icon is a png that contains only the white USB symbol.
I'm suspecting that the background is being added by system.

Now my question is, how I can prevent this kind of modifications.

My device is running KitKat 4.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify a 'large' icon, the system displays the 'small' icon with a standard background, the blue gradient in your case.

You can set a custom image with [`setLargeIcon()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setLargeIcon%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) where you can specify a Bitmap that is shown instead of the default icon. Note: The large icon should have a size of 64x64dp. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14445084/559745) for a concrete example.

Since Android 5.0 you could alternatively use [`setColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor%28int%29) which will set the background color behind the icon. But that obviously won't work for you on Android 4.4.