# how can i set my notification icon large

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications, icons

I am trying to make my notification icon large but it is not working anyway.My device is working on Marshmallow. Can anyone tell me how can i make it possible.

In my image chankyastudent have a notification icon it it is not showing completely in only half of part is showing i want it should be appear completely in icon area.
Can anyone tell me.
Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: can you share your code where you're generating the notification??

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7222442/1744538

Comment: check your notification icon in **Pre  lollipop** devices.
I think this is OS issue

Answer (score 2):

use the dimensions of the notification's large icon to create a scaled bitmap

```
BitmapDrawable contactPicDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) ContactsUtils.getContactPic(mContext, contactId);
    Bitmap contactPic = contactPicDrawable.getBitmap();

    Resources res = mContext.getResources();
    int height = (int) res.getDimension(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height);
    int width = (int) res.getDimension(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width);
    contactPic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(contactPic, width, height, false);
```

set this scaled bitmap as largeIcon it will solve your prblm.

Answer (score 1):

First Of All : It is not from Marshmallow, Notification icon started turning out WHITE or displaying it half from Lollipop itself.

Checkout http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html you will see that the white style is how notifications are meant to be displayed in Android Lollipop.

In Android Lollipop, Google also suggests you to use a color that will be displayed behind the (white) notification icon - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html

You need check your sdk platform is greater than or equal to 23.0.0

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Marshmallow)
{

    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.logo));
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working still i am getting half of image

Comment: @Sushil  okay   please dont check the SDK condition and Use  this below code

`Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setContentText(data)
                .setContentTitle("Notification from Parse")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);`

Comment: still no progress